# Did the 2018 World Chess Championship feature any theoretical novelties in the Sveshnikov Sicilian?

Tags: opening, theory, sicilian-defense, world-championship, sveshnikov

I am interested in how the Sveshnikov theory developed in the last decade, and one of the biggest events heavily featuring it was the WCC match in 2018. Very few books on the opening were published since then.

Did the match contribute something to the opening theory of the Sveshnikov?

Links to articles or annotated games are very welcome, as well as references to books or other material covering the novelties.

Comment: Technically speaking, every game features a novelty at some point, either from White or Black. Unless it was exactly the same as another game until the very end.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance: but not all novelties change opening theory, for instance if they are in lines that are considered suboptimal and the novelty doesn't change that verdict.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yes, those are far rarer. Most novelties even at the top level tend to be difficult to face OTB, but later on an optimal reply is found. It may have already been known beforehand by the player employing the novelty too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carlsen introduced 8... Ne7 (after 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nf6 5.Nc3 e5 6.Ndb5 d6 7.Nd5 Nxd5 8.exd5) instead of 8...Nb8. He played this in round 12 and then again in game two of the tiebreak. The line was known before but not played at the highest level and therefore not considered a serious approach by black.

You can find the analyzed games here at [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/article/view/world-chess-championship-2018-carlsen-caruana). 12... h5 is given as novelty in this line.